# delete the lines that don't have 4 columns

Tags: sed, awk

I have some files as follows.I would like to delete the lines that don't have 4 columns.

```
263 126.9   263 50.2
264 76.6    264 6.2
265 62.3    265 49.9
266 84.2    266 18.3
7   63.8
8   59.7
9   36.4
11  12.0
```

Desired output

```
263 126.9   263 50.2
264 76.6    264 6.2
265 62.3    265 49.9
266 84.2    266 18.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's straight forward with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'NF==4' input.txt
```

`NF` is the number of fields, if it is equal to `4`, the default action is executed, which is printing the whole line.

Comment: Or just for completeness' sake `grep -Ev '^[^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){3}$' input.txt`

Comment: @Jotne In the general case, that's wrong, as it would print lines with five fields or more as well. Exactly four fields is how I interpret the requirement, at least.

Comment: @pfnuesel Code worked well. Thank you! Is it possible in-place editing in awk?

Comment: Can you please outline what you'd like to do?

Comment: @pfnuesel Please leave my question. I got the solution for in-place editing in awk. Thank you!

Comment: `awk` does not have in-place editing, but you can do: `awk 'NF==4' input.txt > tmp & mv tmp input.txt`

Comment: @Jotne - newer releases of GNU awk do have inplace editing: `gawk -i inplace 'script' file`. Usually the tmp file solution as you showed is absolutely fine though and IMHO clearer.

Comment: @EdMorton nice to now. I guess it wold be in 4.x then.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{3\}[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ !d'
```

in this sample, optimization with

```
sed '/\([0-9.]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{3\}[0-9.]\{1,\}/ !d'
```

including remark of sudo_O for 4 column ONLY (other allow more to be printed) and a parameter variable for number of column (must be at least 2)

```
ColNbr=4
ColBefore=$(( ${ColNbr} - 1 ))
sed "/^\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{${ColBefore}\}[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]*$/ !d"
```

As he state, sed is not the optimize tools to use in this case (read comment for arguments)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get errors as follows sed: -e expression #1, char 53: Unmatched ( or \(
sed: -e expression #1, char 63: unterminated address regex

Comment: sorry copy a bad version (missing ] ans 1 \). Correction made in answer. Alos in gnu sed you maybe need a --posix parameter

Comment: @sudo_O: explain why is it not a good tool (performance, code reading, ...) for this kind of job.

Comment: I don't know if the 600 character limit is enough to explain all the reasons. Firstly, readability.. Look at the awk solution, now look at yours! It is not obviously at all what your script does even for `sed` experts. Secondly, flexibility, what if the field separator changes or the field values could contain strings, you would have to  completely rewrite you solution. `sed` was not designed to work with records, `awk` was. Thirdly regular expressions are expensive, especially as the become large and are not anchored like yours. `Python`, `Perl` and `AWK` are much better tools for the job!

Comment: And for what it's worth, if `sed` was the only tool available on a system at the time then I would have done `sed -r '/^(\S+\s+){3}\S+$/!d' file`

Comment: 600 char limit ? depend on version. Performance, sed is often faster, especially on huge text file. Separator, how does awk work with different separator or escaped separator with same separator in data content or simply complex separator like ?ML files. In absolute sed, awk, ?grep or even pur script shell is not better or worst. You are right in this simple task (for awk) that it is a better choice, not that sed is a wrong tools. Purpose of the site is not to give only specific answer to specific question but also to have the concept that can be reused in a similar kind of problem.

Comment: linux and gnu sed is not the only environement, sed with \s doesn't work on lot of other system nor the + and your sed doesn not work on line with trailing blank like mine on more than 4 column (still give a + on your sed because it answer the question in requested environment)

Comment: Comments are limited to 600 characters, what is the confusion about that? Don't make claims about performance with out backing them up. I can assure you that doing un-anchored regular expression matching on every line will be expensive. The awk solution is not using regexs but will be doing byte operations. Benchmark for yourself. If the separator changes, in `awk` you'd just tack on FS='5' where `5` is the new separator, simple, this would completely mess up your ranges and you'd have to rewrite the script. Did I mention the difficulty in debugging regexs!? Of course a language designed

Comment: *Continued*....For this exact kind of text processing *(i.e. `awk`, `perl`)* will be better choices for all the reasons I already described. The purpose of this site is to help steer people in right direction with there problems, this is not the right direction. If you don't know the different between `BRE`, `ERE` and `PCRE` and which `seds` support them and how then you should go and find out, as escaping everything is a hack a not a feature *(introduced by GNU actually)*. This incompatible between different versions of `sed` doesn't really support you argument for `sed` being a good choice.

Comment: I didn't even mention yet that you solution is incorrect *(because it's not anchored).* Add lines with more the 4 fields to the file and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\S+/&/4;t;d' file
```